# Cropping images in PHP leaves black space

Tags: php, gd, crop

This is likely a duplicate, but every solution I have looked at seems to not work for me, so not sure what I am doing differently.

I don't understand too much about image manipulation yet, but cropping images seems to add lots of black space around the right/bottom of the image when using imagecopyresampled to place it over another. They are all JPEGs.

This is my crop function:

```
function thumbImage($thumb_img,$img_size,$shape){
    $width = 250;
    $height = 250;

    list($w, $h) = $img_size;

    if($w > $h) {
            $new_height =   $height;
            $new_width  =   floor($w * ($new_height / $h));
            $crop_x     =   ceil(($w - $h) / 2);
            $crop_y     =   0;
    } else {
            $new_width  =   $width;
            $new_height =   floor( $h * ( $new_width / $w ));
            $crop_x     =   0;
            $crop_y     =   ceil(($h - $w) / 2);
    }

    $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $thumb_img, 0, 0, $crop_x, $crop_y, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

    return $tmp_img;
}
```

Any solutions with an explanation of how it works would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function thumbImage($source_img,$max_size){

    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($source_img);

    if($w>$h){
        $width = ($max_size/$h)*$w;
        $height = $max_size;
    }else{
        $width = $max_size;
        $height = ($max_size/$w)*$h;
    }

    $x = ($max_size-$width)/2;
    $y = ($max_size-$height)/2;

    $thumb_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_size,$max_size);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb_img, $source_img, $x, $y, 0, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);

    return $thumb_img;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it is exactly the same outcome, I can add the code where I am adding the image over another if the issue could possibly be there?

Comment: Yes, please post that. The code I posted should work, I use it myself without problems.